# Checker Board and Pieces Detection OpenCV

Tags: python, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am making a Computer Vision project that consists of a classic game of checkers with AI min max algorithm with alpha beta pruning which I have already made and it works fine. The next part is using computer vision to detect the board and the piece from the screenshot, ([this is what my board looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ6FC.png))

Then I would draw an arrow on the screenshot where I should move next using the already made min max algo. If anyone has any pointers or ways to go around this will be appreciated :).